# prism 5.0 InvokeCommandAction SelectionMode="Multiple"

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, prism-5

I want to detect all selected items in List Box through InvokeCommandAction  prism 5.0.

**XAML**:

```
<Window x:Class="Selection.Prism5._0.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Selection.Prism5"
    xmlns:prism="http://www.codeplex.com/prism"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Height="350"
    Width="525">
<FrameworkElement.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel />
</FrameworkElement.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
             SelectionMode="Multiple">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectItemsCommand}"
                                           TriggerParameterPath="AddedItems" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

</Grid>
```

**View Model**:

```
  public class MainViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.Items = new List<Model>
        {
           new Model {Id=1,Name="Name 1" },
           new Model {Id=2,Name="Name 2" },
           new Model {Id=3,Name="Name 3" },
           new Model {Id=4,Name="Name 4" },
           new Model {Id=5,Name="Name 5" },
           new Model {Id=6,Name="Name 6" }
        };
        SelectItemsCommand = new DelegateCommand<object[]>((items) =>
        {
            if (items != null && items.Count() > 0)
            {
                SelectedItems = items.Select(i => (Model)i);
            }
        });

    }



    public ICommand SelectItemsCommand { get; private set; }

    private IEnumerable<Model> _items;
    public IEnumerable<Model> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set
        {
            _items = value; base.OnPropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }


    private IEnumerable<Model> _selectedItems;
    public IEnumerable<Model> SelectedItems
    {
        get { return _selectedItems; }
        set
        {
            _selectedItems = value; base.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItems");
        }
    }
    private Model _selectedItem;
    public Model SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value; base.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    }
}
```

It should work, however it doesn't. When I select more than one item in GUI:

[image]

View model code recognizes only one item:

[image]

I saw this example in ["What's New in Prism 5.0"](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/prism-50-whats-new/table-of-contents) by Brian Lagunas and as far as I understood, this technic may be used for multi-selection too.
What have I done wrong here?

Comment: You are selecting one item at a time and the command is invoked for each one of them. This is the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

*SelectionChangedEventArgs.AddedItems* gives you the selection list of a particular action. if ListBox `SelectionMode` is `"Multiple"` or `"Single"` you cannot select multiple items at a single click. if ListBox `SelectionMode` is `"Extended"` you can select multiple items with the help of the shift key.

*SelectionChangedEventArgs.AddedItems* will not give all selected items of the list box for a particular action.

For your need,

In View,

Change `TriggerParameterPath="AddedItems"` to `TriggerParameterPath="Source.SelectedItems"` .

In ViewModel

Change `DelegateCommand<object[]>` to `DelegateCommand<System.Collections.ICollection>`

Ref:
http://frststart.blogspot.com/2016/10/selectionchangedselecteditemstutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting one item at a time and the command is invoked for each time you select an item.

This is the expected behaviour.

If you want to keep track of the currently selected items you could add an `IsSelected` property to the `Model` class and use an `ItemContainerStyle` to bind this one to the `IsSelected` property of the `ListBoxItem` container:

```
<ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
             SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectItemsCommand}"
                                           TriggerParameterPath="AddedItems" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

---

```
SelectItemsCommand = new DelegateCommand<System.Collections.IList>((items) =>
{
    SelectedItems = Items.Where(x => x.IsSelected).ToList();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for idea. That may work, however I consider this solution as too tricky: 
1). Usage of prism
2). Even Trigger
3). Command binding
Whereas it possible to resolve it with one behavior and few lines of code.
Does it mean that there is no straightforward solution for multi selection with prism?

Comment: Tricky? No, this is how the MVVM pattern works. If you think this is solution is "tricky" you should learn MVVM. And Prism just passes the actual value of the AddedItems property of the EventArgs to the command and this will only contain the newly selected item as I explained in my answer. Prism has nothing to do with this.

Comment: KIS. I don't like to write redundant code.
I don't need to use all of these tricks to implement multi selection because it may be implemented very simple by using custom behavior and binding to SelectedItems. Simpler with much less code either in xaml and code behind.
I've done it before, but I though that prism may do it simpler. I was wrong.

Comment: Kind of  resolved :) I'll still use behaviors. 
I just tried to use features from prism5.0.
According to the video course I mentioned above, it's possible to implement multi-selection through prism and I won't need to write behavior for multiselection.  
Thanks.

Comment: As mentioned you should keep track of the selected items in the view model but the InvokeCommandAction will only pass the latest selected item to the command. I guess this answers your original question. If you have another issue you should ask a new question.